# How to run select query on columns having comma separated values

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like, instr

I know how to separate comma-separated column values into different columns. However, my question is how to query these columns in a where condition. I have a sample table named '*Details*' below.

```
    User      Department
    ----      ----------
    User1     Admin, Accounts
    User2     Admin
    User3     Admin, Finance
```

Suppose I want to query the user who is in an `Admin` but not in `Finance`.  As you can see, **User1** and **User2** satisfy the condition, but **User3** doesn't.

How can I build a select query to get the **User3** as result

I know the 'like' operator can be used, but not sure how.

```
SELECT USER 
FROM DETAILS 
WHERE DEPARTMENT LIKE "Admin"||"Accounts" 
AND NOT LIKE "Finance";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the operator `LIKE`:

```
SELECT USER 
FROM DETAILS 
WHERE ',' || DEPARTMENT || ',' LIKE '%,' || 'Admin' || ',%'
  AND ',' || DEPARTMENT || ',' LIKE '%,' || 'Finance' || ',%'
  AND ',' || DEPARTMENT || ',' NOT LIKE '%,' || 'Accounts' || ',%';
```

Or the function `INSTR()`:

```
SELECT USER 
FROM DETAILS 
WHERE INSTR(',' || DEPARTMENT || ',', ',' || 'Admin' || ',') > 0
  AND INSTR(',' || DEPARTMENT || ',', ',' || 'Finance' || ',') > 0
  AND INSTR(',' || DEPARTMENT || ',', ',' || 'Accounts' || ',') = 0;
```

This will work if there are no spaces after each comma in the column `DEPARTMENT`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=865b3ae559324c32c68d5c18cb92cbb6).

Comment: That worked out well !

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a question about a problem with the database design.  The problem disappears when the design error is rectified.

Specifically, your database is not 1NF: not in First Normal Form.  The department is not a scalar value, but represents a repeating group.  1NF requires all repeating groups be eliminated.

Normal forms were invented to help database designers define databases that can be fully exploited by SQL.  In the case of repeating groups, SQL has no operator for the *nth* value in a group (especially not in SQLite, where the repeating group is just a string).

To normalize your table, create this:

```
User      Department
----      ----------
User1     Admin
User1     Accounts
User2     Admin
User3     Admin
User3     Finance
```

Now your query can be written using *existential quantification*.  In SQL, that takes the form of `where not exists (...)`

Comment: I understand the discrepancy in DB design, but unfortunately, my privilege is limited to SELECT operations only. What you pointed out is the right way.